# Reshaping 4-dimensional array to 5-dimensional array in R using "aperm"

Tags: r, arrays, reshape

I am seeking to reshape a 4-dimensional array in R to a 5-dimensional array using "aperm". The original array is [40,50,50,130], corresponding to data of 40 images with dimensions of 50x50 cells and 130 total bands. However, these 130 bands is distributed over 26 images of 5 bands a piece (26*5=130). I would like to reshape this array into [40,5,50,50,26] if possible, with the second dimension corresponding the bands of each image. I have tried using the "aperm" function to do this:

```
tiff_reshapen = array( aperm(tiff_concatenate,c(4,3,2,1)), dim =c(40, 5, 50, 50, 26) )
```

where "tiff_reshapen" is the new 5-dimensional output array, and the 4-dimensional input is "tiff_concatenate".

However, I cannot get the output images to match those of the input and they are reshapen incorrectly. I think it is because I am confused by the permutation vector in the aperm function (i.e., c(4,3,2,1)). I have tried every permutation of these 4 dimensions but none of them are working to match my original data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One of `aperm(array(x, c(40, 50, 50, 26, 5)), c(1, 5, 2, 3, 4))` and `aperm(array(x, c(40, 50, 50, 5, 26), c(1, 4, 2, 3, 5))` should do what you want.  Hard to know without an example ...